# Calling now() in a function

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

One of our Postgres tables, called rep_event, has a timestamp column that indicates when each row was inserted.  But all of the rows have a timestamp value of 2000-01-01 00:00:00, so something isn't set up right.

There is a function that inserts rows into the table, and it is the only code that inserts rows into that table - no other code inserts into that table.  (There also isn't any code that updates the rows in that table.)  Here is the definition of the function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION handle_event() RETURNS "trigger"
AS $$
BEGIN
    IF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
        INSERT INTO rep_event SELECT 'D', TG_RELNAME, OLD.object_id, now();
        RETURN OLD;
    ELSIF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
        INSERT INTO rep_event SELECT 'U', TG_RELNAME, NEW.object_id, now();
        RETURN NEW;
    ELSIF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
        INSERT INTO rep_event SELECT 'I', TG_RELNAME, NEW.object_id, now();
        RETURN NEW;
    END IF;
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Here is the table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE rep_event
(
operation character(1) NOT NULL,
table_name text NOT NULL,
object_id bigint NOT NULL,
time_stamp timestamp without time zone NOT NULL
)
```

As you can see, the now() function is called to get the current time.  Doing a "select now()" on the database returns the correct time, so is there an issue with calling now() from within a function?

Comment: Can you show me the trigger definition? What table is it tied to?

Comment: Very strange. There should be no problem calling `now()` inside the function, I'd bet there is some problems elsewhere. BTW, if that's intended to be a creation/modification timestamp, it should better be a "timestamp with timezone" (not intuitive, but so it is), and instead of `now()` better call `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. But this is not essential.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simpler solution is to just modify your table definition to have NOW() be the default value:

```
CREATE TABLE rep_event (
    operation character(1) NOT NULL,
    table_name text NOT NULL,
    object_id bigint NOT NULL,
    time_stamp timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW()
);
```

Then you can get rid of the now() calls in your trigger.

Also as a side note, I strongly suggest including the column ordering in your function... IOW;

```
INSERT INTO rep_event (operation,table_name,object_id,time_stamp) SELECT ...
```

This way if you ever add a new column or make other table changes that change the internal ordering of the tables, your function won't suddenly break.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem has to be elsewhere, as your function works well. Create test database, paste the code you cited and run:

```
create table events (object_id bigserial, data text);
create trigger rep_event
  before insert or update or delete on events
  for each row execute procedure handle_event();

insert into events (data) values ('v1'),('v2'),('v3');
delete from events where data='v2';
update events set data='v4' where data='v3';

select * from events;
```

```
     object_id | data 
    -----------+------
             1 | v1
             3 | v4
```

```
select * from rep_event;
```

```
     operation | table_name | object_id |         time_stamp         
    -----------+------------+-----------+----------------------------
     I         | events     |         1 | 2011-07-08 10:31:50.489947
     I         | events     |         2 | 2011-07-08 10:31:50.489947
     I         | events     |         3 | 2011-07-08 10:31:50.489947
     D         | events     |         2 | 2011-07-08 10:32:12.65699
     U         | events     |         3 | 2011-07-08 10:32:33.662936
    (5 rows)
```

Check other triggers, trigger creation command etc. And change this `timestamp without timezone` to `timestamp with timezone`.